# How to switch between differant referance links in MS-word

Tags: ms-word

I am writing a document in MS word. I've several links in the starting pages of the document, these link are pointing to some place in the same document.

If I click on one of the link, the curser is going to the intended location accyrately. Now my question is How can I again go to the previous page (The page with links) from the current page.

Please help me. As the document is so big, It is becoming dificult for me to check all the links are working correctly.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean bookmarks? You can do a lot with VBA.

```
Sub Links()
Dim hl As Hyperlink

For Each hl In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    Debug.Print hl.Range
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(hl.Range) Then
        Debug.Print "Exists"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Missing"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```